# Android Project not running on emulator.in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

when I run android project on emulator,the emulator starts but after some time console in my eclipse says:

```
emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.and.test.pahse1.Phase1AndEngineActivity      activity launch'!
```

What is this problem?
One more thing I want to mention is that when I run the project it asks to select the webcam and when I do something like cancel ok or apply then emulator runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reset your adb.

In Eclipse, go to window... show view... Other... Android... Devices

I came across this problem a while back and I think this is how I figured it out